# Insert Into Statement has Missing Operator

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I cannot figure out where the missing operator is in this line:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Site_Data" _
 & " ([Pass_Fail], [Tag_Name], [PM_#], [Group_Location_Reference], [Device_Type], [Manufacturer_SN], [Year_Put_Into_Service], [Date_of_Test], [Time_To_Complete], [Description], [Set_Point], [Set_Point_Units], [Fail_Low], [Fail_High], [As_Found], [As_Left], [Date_RFS/Idle], [Comments], [Year], [Month], [Site])" _
 & " SELECT [Pass_Fail], [Tag_Name], [PM_#], [Group_Location_Reference], [Device_Type], [Manufacturer_SN], [Year_Put_Into_Service], [Date_of_Test], [Time_To_Complete], [Description], [Set_Point], [Set_Point_Units], [Fail_Low], [Fail_High], [As_Found], [As_Left], [Date_RFS/Idle], [Comments], " & yrs & " As [Year], " & Mnth & " As [Month], " & SiteName & " As [Site]" _
 & " FROM " & tbl.Name & ";"
```

#### Edit

Ok So the variable yrs = "2013" works but the variable **mnth = "April"** does not as well as **site = "Fun_Land"**

Comment: I would like to point out that all the variables are assign and receiving vales.

Comment: Please show us the text of the SQL statement which fails (not the code which creates that statement) and include the full text of any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked some of the variables when I attempted to diagnose your SQL statement text.  Despite my error, the advice I offered is still sound:  give yourself an opportunity to examine the completed statement before you `Execute` it.

```
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO Site_Data" _
    & " ([Pass_Fail], [Tag_Name], [PM_#], [Group_Location_Reference], [Device_Type], [Manufacturer_SN], [Year_Put_Into_Service], [Date_of_Test], [Time_To_Complete], [Description], [Set_Point], [Set_Point_Units], [Fail_Low], [Fail_High], [As_Found], [As_Left], [Date_RFS/Idle], [Comments], [Year], [Month], [Site])" _
    & " SELECT [Pass_Fail], [Tag_Name], [PM_#], [Group_Location_Reference], [Device_Type], [Manufacturer_SN], [Year_Put_Into_Service], [Date_of_Test], [Time_To_Complete], [Description], [Set_Point], [Set_Point_Units], [Fail_Low], [Fail_High], [As_Found], [As_Left], [Date_RFS/Idle], [Comments], " & yrs & " As [Year], " & Mnth & " As [Month], " & SiteName & " As [Site]" _
    & " FROM " & tbl.Name & ";"
Debug.Print strInsert
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailonError
```

You can then view the completed statement in the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you there).  For troubleshooting, you can copy the statement text, create a new query in the query designer, switch to SQL View and paste in the statement text there.  Modify the statement in the query designer to get it working.  Then revise your code to produce the same working statement.

Comment: So you are saying I cannot use tbl.name?

Comment: No.  I am saying use a string variable to hold your `INSERT` statement text.  Then `Debug.Print` the variable to see the actual statement the code build.  You can give the string to `CurrentDb.Execute` to execute it.

Comment: I used *tblFoo* because I have no idea what value your `tbl.Name` returns.

Comment: Ok so I was messing around and got the error Too Few Parameters. Expected 2. But when I sub numbers into the variables and run in SQL view of a query it works?

Comment: Copy the text from `Debug.Print`.  Paste it into SQL View of a new Access query.  When you run the query and Access presents message boxes asking for the parameter values, notice those boxes include the names of what Access thinks are the parameters.  What are those names?  If you can't spot the problem, show us the statement text and the names of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I have solved my question for anyone with the same problem when you are assigning a string to a variable you need to make sure the string is such that it has '' example Mnth = "'April'".